# Is there a way to rebuild ehcache on expiry

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I am building an endpoint in my spring boot application which pulls data from multiple sources processes it according to user input and returns the result. The pulling of data requires lot of time. I don't want the requester to wait till the network data is fetched every time as the data does not update very often. Hence, I added ehcache into the system which caches pulled network data to improve performance.

My cache expiry time is 15 mins. I would like to know if there is an built-in way to rebuild the cache automatically on some another thread after it is expired. I have tried using timer task. It works, but looks like a hack. I have gone through the documentation but could not find any reference to rebuild cache on expiry.

```java
    @Cacheable("channels")
    public List<Channel> fetchAllData() {
        // expensive network calls
    }
```

Also, is ehcache the right candidate for my requirement or should I look for something else?
Thank you.

Comment: How is the cache initially seeded with data? First time it's used? Then that is also when the cache will be re-seeded, i.e. on first use after expiration. --- If not on "first use", but you pre-seed the cache on startup, then don't expire the cache at all. Create a background job that runs every 15 mins, retrieves fresh data then updates the cache, so the cache is always available, and is updated atomically when the new data has been pulled.

Comment: Ehcache 2.x has `RefreshAheadCache`, but 3.x seems to have dropped this feature. Other caching libraries have similar support, like Guava's `refreshAfterWrite`.